# Parallelize calculations

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, parallel-processing, future

I need to calculate the mean and extract the root of some numbers from a huge file:

```
1, 2, 3, 4, 5,\n
6, 7, 8, 9, 10,\n
11, 12, 13, 14,15,\n
...
```

This is the code:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class App1{

    int res, c;
    double mean, root;
    ArrayList list = new ArrayList();

    public App1() {
        // einlesen
        Scanner sc = null;
        try {
            sc = new Scanner(new File("file.txt")).useDelimiter("[,\\s]+");
        } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
            System.err.println(ex);
        }
        while (sc.hasNextInt()) {
            list.add(sc.nextInt());
            res += (int) list.get(c);
            c++;
        }
        sc.close();

        // Mean
        mean = res / list.size();

        // Root
        root = Math.sqrt(mean);

        System.out.println("Mean: " + mean);
        System.out.println("Root: " + root);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    App1 app = new App1();
    }
}
```

Is there any way to parallelize it?

Before calculating the mean I need all the numbers, so one thread can't calculate while another is still fetching the numbers from the file.
The same thing with extracting the root: A thread can't extract it from the mean if the mean isn't calculated yet.

I thought about [Future](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Future.html), would that be a solution?

Comment: I don't know java multithreading well enough to answer this. But the best way to parallelize reading from a file is to read from the file in one thread, and have the other thread get notified to process by a condition var. Depending on the complexity of the processing you could have multiple threads doing it

Comment: If the logic cannot be paralleled, then the code cannot.

Comment: Would it make sense to read the file line by line and do calculations with these lines in another thread? Then merging the results, like fork/join?

Comment: Here's the only thing I can think of.  You could read 100 or so lines from the file, just as Strings, then make a new thread which parses outs the integers and adds them up.  You could do this over and over, where one thread just reads text, and new threads parse it and do the arithmetic.  At the end, you interrogate each thread for its total, and how many numbers it found, and add them all up.

Comment: ... but you typed that idea yourself before I did!

Comment: If you're looking for excuse to do concurrent processing, you can implement your own idea. Otherwise, I doubt that you will see any measurable time improvement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's something critical you will have to accept up front - **you will not be able to process the data any faster than you can read it from the file**. So first time how long it will take to read through the whole file and accept that you won't improve on that.

That said - have you considered a [ForkJoinPool](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ForkJoinPool.html).

Answer (score 1):

You can calculate the mean in parallel, because the mean is simply the sum divided by the count. There is no reason why you cannot sum up the values in parallel, and count them as well, then just do the division later.

Consider a class:

```
public class PartialSum() {
    private final int partialcount;
    private final int partialsum;
    public PartialSum(int count, int sum) {
        partialsum = sum;
        partialcount = count;
    public int getCount() {
        return partialcount;
    }
    public int getSum() {
        return partialsum;
    }
}
```

Now, this could be the return type of a Future, as in `Future<PartialSum>`.

So, what you need to do is split the file in parts, and then send the parts to individual threads.

Each thread calculates a `PartialSum`. Then, as the threads complete, you can:

```
int sum = 0;
int count = 0;
for(Future<PartialSum> partial : futures) {
    PartialSum ps = partial.get();
    sum += ps.getSum();
    count += ps.getCount();
}

double mean = (double)sum / count;
double root = ....
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it's possible.

1. int offset = (filesize / Number of Threads)
2. Create n threads
3. Each thread starts reading from offset * thread number. Eg Thread 0 starts reading from byte 0, thread 1 starts reading from offset * 1, thread 2 starts reading from offset * 2
4. If thread num != 0, read ahead until you hit a newline character - start from there.
5. Add up an average per thread. Save to "thread_average" or something.
6. When all threads are finished, total average = average of all "thread_average" variables
7. Square root the total average variable.

It will need a bit of messing around to make sure the threads don't read too far into another threads block of the file, but should be do-able

Comment: So at the beginning, all threads are reading from the file at the same time?  I suspect that this will make the program slower, not faster.

Comment: It really depends on what you're doing and your disk throughput and latency. OP's calculation is so simple that I think you're correct: the bottleneck with this application will always be in the disk I/O.

Answer (score 0):

No there is no way to parallelize this. Although you could do something that looks like you are using threading, the result will be overly complex but still run at about the same speed as before.

The reason for this is that file access is and has to be single-threaded, and beside reading from file all you do is two add operations. So in best case those add operations could be parallelized, however since those take almost no execution time, the gain would be like 5% - 10% at best. And that time is negated (or worse) by the thread creation and maintenance.

Once thing you can do to speed things up would be to remove the part where you put things into a list (assuming that you don't need those values later).

```
 while (sc.hasNextInt()) {
   res += sc.nextInt();
   ++c;
 }

 mean = res / c;
```